# How to Find & Remove instead of replace

Tags: editor, atom-editor

I'm using Atom as my editor for projects. When i get existing projects and want to remove elements from several files, i want to make a "Search and Replace" throughout my project.

**But instead of replacing the element, i want to remove it.**

> Is there a string or symbol which i can put into the replace field to
>   "remove" my searched element?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Atom, but with a typical editor you would remove the found item by replacing it with an empty string.

Comment: I'm trying to do this but can't figure out how to write empty string.

Comment: In this context, "empty string" means no characters.  How do you write no characters?  By not writing any characters ... of course.